# How to use multiple scopes in a @RestrictTo annotation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, annotations

I'm using @RestrictTo annotation to denote that a function should be used in only in subclasses or tests.

To do that I use the following syntax:

```kotlin
    @RestrictTo(value = [SUBCLASSES, TESTS])
    public override fun onCleared() {
        // Expose protected fun onCleared for tests
    }
```

At first it seemed to be working but my teammates reported Android Studio showing this warning:

[image: error-screen-shot]

I could reproduce this after building the project again.

This error goes away if I remove the TESTS scope from the annotation as if the annotation does not support multiple scopes in values.

Do you think if this is the intended behavior of the annotation?

Can you think another way to restrict a function to the union of two different scopes?

Thanks in advance